# Adding dedup _raw before timechart returns 0 results

Tags: splunk

I apologize if this is asked already but I search to no avail.

When writing a Splunk query that will eventually be used for summary indexing using sitimechart, I have this query:

```
index=app sourcetype=<removed> host=<removed> earliest=-10d
    | eval Success_Count=if(scs=="True",1,0)
    | eval Failure_Count=if(scs=="False",1,0)
    | timechart span=1d sum(Success_Count) as SuccessCount sum(Failure_Count) as FailureCount count as TotalCount by host
```

Results are as expected.  However, some data was accidentally indexed twice, so I need to remove duplicates.  If I'm doing a regular search, I just use `| dedup _raw` to remove the identical events.  However, if I run the following query, I get zero results returned (no matter where I put `| dedup _raw`):

```
index=app sourcetype=<removed> host=<removed> earliest=-10d
    | dedup _raw
    | eval Success_Count=if(scs=="True",1,0)
    | eval Failure_Count=if(scs=="False",1,0)
    | timechart span=1d sum(Success_Count) as SuccessCount sum(Failure_Count) as FailureCount count as TotalCount by host
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Splunk 4.3.2.

I've also posted this identical question to the Splunk>Answers page.  I will remove if that is against terms.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using such an old version of Splunk (we're on 6.0.2 right now, and soon 6.1). There are only a few exceptional use case for summary indexing now. Report acceleration and data model acceleration is much faster and easier to manage.

Comment: Also why are you trying to `dedup _raw`? Are you saying you have the exact same events with the same message and timestamp? If so, then you have deeper issues.

Comment: The version is so far out because I work at a large enterprise that hasn't prioritized the upgrade (for whatever reason they have).  It is schedule for early this year, however.  And I was `dedup _raw` to eliminate exact same events -- someone messed with our index configs in the code repo and deployed changes without our knowledge, which caused a re-index of text logging.  I also do have deeper, unresolvable issues with Splunk, especially being so far out of version

Comment: If you want to clean it up, then you can find the duplicate events and use the `| delete` command, which essentially hides the events (but still irreversible). You'll need the `can_delete` role, which even admins don't have by default. Just be careful with the `| delete` command!